# MediaElement capture microphone and modify the data

Tags: c++, windows, audio, microsoft-metro

I was planning to capture microphone with MediaCapture under windows 8 using c++. Is it possible to somehow get the pcm data and modify it with my algorithm?

Comment: Have you checked [Recording and playing PCM audio on Windows 8 (VB)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/460145/Recording-and-playing-PCM-audio-on-Windows-8-VB) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible using MediaCapture by writing a C++ class which derives `IMediaElement` and IMFTransform then calling `AddEffectAsync` with any properties to pass into the transform stored in a `IPropertySet`/`PropertyBag` object.